# How can I pass the authenticated User Id to the class library project in asp.net core via DI?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a NLayers application:

- asp.net core mvc
- asp.net web api

and some of my **class libraries**:

- DataLayer
- DomainClasses
- Models
- Services

here is my BaseService in ServicesLayer:

```
public abstract partial class BaseService 
{
   protected BaseService(AppDbContext dbContext
                        , UserManager<MyApplicationUser> userManager
                        , int authenticatedUserId)
   {
       DbContext = dbContext;
       AuthenticatedUserId = authenticatedUserId;
       MyUserManager = userManager;

       Init();
  }

  public AppDbContext DbContext { get; }
  protected UserManager<MyApplicationUser> MyUserManager;
  public string AuthenticatedUserId { get; }

  protected virtual void Init()
  {
    // 
  }

  ...
```

}

and one of my child service classes:

```
public class BookService :BaseService
{
   public BookService(AppDbContext dbContext
       , UserManager<MyApplicationUser> userManager 
        , int authenticatedUserId)

        :base(dbContext,userManager, authenticatedUserId)
    {

    }
}
```

I want to access the **authenticated user id** (from Asp net core) in my services (class library). How can I pass it via DI or something else?

**Updated based on @Frank's suggestion:**

```
public class CommonServicesContainer
{
    public AppDbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    public AppUserManager UserManager { get; set; }
    public int AuthenticatedUserId{ get; set; }

    public CommonServicesContainer(AppDbContext appDbContext, AppUserManager userManager, string authenticatedUserId)
    {
        DbContext = dbContext;
        UserManager = userManager;
        AuthenticatedUserId = autheticatedUserId;
    }
}
```

my startup:

```
        services.AddScoped<AppDbContext>();
        services.AddScoped<AppUserManager>();

        services.AddScoped(x =>
        {
            var authenticatedUserId = x.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            return new CommonServicesContainer(x.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>()
                                         , x.GetRequiredService<AppUserManager>()
                                         , authenticatedUserId);
        });
```

AccountController :

```
private readonly CommonServicesContainer _commonServicesContainer;

public AccountController(CommonServicesContainer commonServicesContainer)
{
    _commonServicesContainer = commonServicesContainer;

    // ...
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
{
   // ... 
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
                var isValid = await _usersService.AreCredentialsValidAsync(model.Username, model.Password);

   if(isValid)
   {
       var foundUser = await _usersService.GetByUserNameAsync(model.Username);

                        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                                        foundUser.SubjectId,                         
                                        foundUser.UserName);

                        //_commonServicesContainer.AuthenticatedUserId = foundUser.Id;
                        // ...

   }
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I see that I can inject **IHttpContextAccessor** to my classes, but I have to inject it into all the children's class constructors, and it gets very crowded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by register a AuthenticatedUser type as a AddScoped.

```
class AuthenticatedUser {
  public int? UserId {get;set;}
  public bool IsAuthenticated => int.HasValue;
}
```

in Startup.cs of your AspNetCore project:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
   ...
   services.AddScoped<AuthenticatedUser>();
   ...
}
```

Somewhere you do the authentication, you get the `AuthenticatedUser` and set the UserId.

Since `AuthenticatedUser` is added as scoped it acts as global (same instance) for the particular httprequest scope. So all `.GetService<AuthenticatedUser> / .GetRequiredService<AuthenticatedUser>` will have the same instance - within the same scope.

Each http-request has it is own scope, and thereby also their own `AuthenticatedUser`.

When the user is Authenticated, using AspNetCore Identity, you can find the `AspNetUsers` Id by:

```
if( httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ) {
  var userIdClaim = httpContext.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier");
  var aspNetUsersId = userIdClaim?.Value ?? 0;
}
```

This can be done as Middleware, then setting `AuthenticatedUser.UserId`.

Comment: thanks, but how can I  do this? "Somewhere you do the authentication, you get the `AuthenticatedUser` and set the UserId." 

I Injected the class in `Startup.cs` as u said, and then I set the userId in my `AccountController.Login` method, after `await HttpContext.SignInAsync()` , but I got null in my `ServiceLayer`

Comment: You have to set the `AuthenticatedUser.UserId = x` on every request, since it will be a new scope / instance.  You normally do the with a  Middleware where you set it. How do you get the `authenticatedUserId`?  - show the code.

Comment: Is that the user signin (Username/Password) `AccountController POSTLogin`, or is it done for every request to the backend?

Comment: It is my `User/Password signIn method` in `Controller` and executed only once when the user is signing in, then I want to have the `Authenticated UserId` in my class library

Comment: But you are using the AspNetCore Identity package?

Comment: I updated the `Startup` part of code to set the `AuthenticatedUserId` on every request. Is that correct or not?

Comment: Ok, you have to validate `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to ensure user is authenticated. Secondly is think `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` will contain the email of the user! I will updated my answer.